# In a C# 'using' block, how best to access the IDisposable in contained extension method calls?

Tags: c#, methods, using, weak-references

I am writing extension methods for a class, and would like to access an IDisposable object defined in a using block which will often contain calls to the extension methods.

I do not want to simply pass the IDisposable to the method calls, which would detract from the simplicity of my API's programming model. Accomplishing what I'm after would also make the code work much more like the third-party API with which I'm integrating.

I can imagine one way to go about this: register the IDisposable in some global location, perhaps tied to the current thread ID so it can be looked up in the extension methods via a factory method call or some such thing. The object could unregister itself when the using block is exited and its Dispose() method is eventually called (to make this work I imagine I might need to use a weak reference, though).

That doesn't seem very unclean, but it is a little too much roundabout for my taste.  Is there  some more direct way of doing this?

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods { 

    public static void Foo(this Bar b) {
        // Access t to enable this extension method to do its work, whatever that may be
    }

}

public class Bar {

}

public class Schlemazel {

    public void DoSomething() {

        using (Thingamabob t = new Thingamabob()) {

            Bar b = new Bar();

            b.Foo();

        }

    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

Following is a solution implemented using weak references and a simple thread-based registration system. It seems to work and to be stable even under a fair load, but of course on a really overloaded system it could theoretically start throwing errors due to lock contention.

I thought it might be interesting for someone to see this solution, but again, it introduces needless complexity and I am only willing to do this if necessary. Again, the goal is a clean extension of a third-party API, where I can call extension methods on objects created by the third-party API, where the extension methods depend on some context that is messy to create or get for each little extension method call.

I've left in some console output statements so that if you're curious, you can actually plop these classes into a command-line project and see it all in action.

```
public class Context : IDisposable
{
    private const int MAX_LOCK_TRIES = 3;
    private static TimeSpan MAX_WRITE_LOCK_TIMEOUT = TimeSpan.FromTicks(500);

    private static System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim readerWriterLock = new System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    static IDictionary<string, WeakReference<Context>> threadContexts = new Dictionary<string, WeakReference<Context>>();

    private bool registered;

    private string threadID;
    private string ThreadID
    {
        get { return threadID; }
        set
        {
            if (threadID != null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot associate this context with more than one thread");
            threadID = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a Context suitable for use in a using() statement
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A Context which will automatically deregister itself when it goes out of scope, i.e. at the end of a using block</returns>
    public static Context CreateContext()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CreateContext()");

        return new Context(true);
    }

    private Context(bool register)
    {
        if (register)
        {

        registered = true;
        try
        {
            RegisterContext(this);
        }
        catch
        {
            registered = false;
        }
    }
    else
        registered = false;
}

public Context()
{
    registered = false;
}

public void Process(ThirdPartyObject o, params string[] arguments)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Context.Process(o)");

    // Process o, sometimes using the third-party API which this object has access to
    // This hides away the complexity of accessing that API, including obviating the need
    // to reconstruct and configure heavyweight objects to access it; calling code can 
    // blithely call useful methods on individual objects without knowing the messy details
}

public void Dispose()
{
    if (registered) 
        DeregisterContext(this);
}

private static void RegisterContext(Context c)
{
    if (c == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    c.ThreadID = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("RegisterContext() " + c.ThreadID);

    bool lockEntered = false;
    int tryCount = 0;

    try
    {
        while (!readerWriterLock.TryEnterWriteLock(TimeSpan.FromTicks(5000)))
            if (++tryCount > MAX_LOCK_TRIES)
                throw new OperationCanceledException("Cannot register context (timeout)");

        lockEntered = true;

        threadContexts[c.ThreadID] = new WeakReference<Context>(c);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockEntered)
            readerWriterLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}

private static void DeregisterContext(Context c)
{
    if (c == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    else if (!c.registered)
        return;

    Console.WriteLine("DeregisterContext() " + c.ThreadID);

    bool lockEntered = false;
    int tryCount = 0;

    try
    {
        while (!readerWriterLock.TryEnterWriteLock(TimeSpan.FromTicks(5000)))
            if (++tryCount > MAX_LOCK_TRIES)
                throw new OperationCanceledException("Cannot deregister context (timeout)");

        lockEntered = true;

        if (threadContexts.ContainsKey(c.ThreadID)) 
        {
            Context registeredContext = null;

            if (threadContexts[c.ThreadID].TryGetTarget(out registeredContext))
            {
                if (registeredContext == c)
                {
                    threadContexts.Remove(c.ThreadID);
                }
            }
            else
                threadContexts.Remove(c.ThreadID);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockEntered)
            readerWriterLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the Context for this thread, if one has been registered
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The Context for this thread, which would generally be defined in a using block using Context.CreateContext()</returns>
internal static Context GetThreadContext()
{
    string threadID = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("GetThreadContext() " + threadID);

    bool lockEntered = false;
    int tryCount = 0;

    try
    {
        while (!readerWriterLock.TryEnterReadLock(TimeSpan.FromTicks(5000)))
            if (++tryCount > MAX_LOCK_TRIES)
                throw new OperationCanceledException("Cannot get context (timeout)");

        lockEntered = true;
        Context registeredContext = null;

        if (threadContexts.ContainsKey(threadID))
            threadContexts[threadID].TryGetTarget(out registeredContext);

        return registeredContext;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockEntered)
            readerWriterLock.ExitReadLock();
    }

    }
}

// Imagine this is some third-party API
public static class ThirdPartyApi
{
    // Imagine this is any call to the third-party API that returns an object from that API which we'd like to decorate with an extension method
    public static ThirdPartyObject GetThirdPartyObject()
    {
        return new ThirdPartyObject();
    }
}

// Imagine this is some class from a third-party API, to which we would like to add extension methods
public class ThirdPartyObject
{
    internal ThirdPartyObject() { }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void DoSomething(this ThirdPartyObject o) {
        // get the object I need to access resources to do my work

        Console.WriteLine("o.DoSomething()");

        Context c = Context.GetThreadContext();

        c.Process(o);
    }
}
```

You could test it pretty simply, with some code like this:

```
    ThirdPartyObject o;

    using (Context.CreateContext())
    {
        o = ThirdPartyApi.GetThirdPartyObject(); // or a call to my own code to get it, encapsulating calls to the third-party API

        // Call the method we've tacked on to the third party API item
        o.DoSomething();
    }

    try
    {
        // If the registered context has been disposed/deregistered, this will throw an error;
        // there is of course no way of knowing when it will happen, but in my simple testing
        // even this first attempt always throws an error, on my relatively unburdened system.
        // This means that with this model, one should not access the using-block Context
        // outside of the using block, but that's of course true in general of using statements
        o.DoSomething();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

    try
    {
        // Should almost certainly see an error now
        o.DoSomething();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Please show some code demonstrating what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Show us your code, you are clearly not using the `using` clause as you should in this context.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do and why you're trying to do it. Why do you need to know whether or not the object has been disposed in your extension methods? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Are you sure you meant "...doesn't seem very *unclean*, "? Isn't that saying it's not - not clean?

Comment: @HansPassant I *think* that the `IDisposable` and the `this` object are two different objects.

Comment: No worries--the goal is worthy and I am blissfully happy with my programming style and approach, I mean really super happy. If you have a different solution from mine, please post! :)

Comment: It's very unclear what you've want. It sounds like you've got `SomeMethod{using (Foo f = new Foo()){}` and you want to access `f` outside of `SomeMethod` Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: @C. Lang: Nope, I meant it just as I typed it; I hope you can read my post in a manner that is not unkind. :D

Comment: @Hans Passant: svick is right. 'this' in the extension method is the object calling the method/being extended; the IDisposable we're referring to would be the object in the 'using' statement.

Comment: @ken, I want to use the IDisposable from the extension methods; I'll provide an example now.

Comment: @Conrad Frix, no--I want to use the object 'f' from some other object inside the using block.

Comment: I have no idea why people would vote this technical question down while having no idea how to answer it. Sheesh

Comment: You want to dispose of the class you're operating on in the extension method?

Comment: @Moe, I am writing extension methods for a class, and would like to access an object defined in a using block which will often contain calls to the extension methods.

Comment: @Reed Copsey: I've added some comprehensive samples which should give a better idea. Thanks.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: Sure I am. There is absolutely nothing wrong with what I'm doing. Samples included. In general it degrades the quality of these boards when someone is so blunt (and bluntly wrong), but to each their own.

Comment: @HansPassant: I hope the examples are clearer than my original post. Thanks again for looking.

Comment: @ken: Comprehensive samples are included now. Thank you!

Comment: @svick: I've added a sample above which shows my last-resort way of doing it. Thoughts are welcome.

Comment: @Conrad Frix: Please check out the added samples.  Hope this is more clear.

Comment: @Moe: Are these samples more clear? Again, I am not in favor of such a technical approach if there is a much simpler one.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `t` variable to the extension method.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods { 
    public static void Foo(this Bar b, Thingamabob t) {
        // Access t to enable this extension method to do its work, whatever that may be
    }
}

public class Bar { }

public class Schlemazel {
    public void DoSomething() {
        using (Thingamabob t = new Thingamabob()) {
            Bar b = new Bar();
            b.Foo(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's one obvious way that I should've excluded. I am not slamming your response. In an object-oriented way it is not terribly unclean--like "Here, go to the store, and take my car to help you get there". It just doesn't lead to the simple programming model I'm after for my API, which makes use of another which also works a similar way to what I'm after. The objects where I want to call the extension methods are generated internally by that API, but in order to modify them requires accesss to other objects from that API, which mine encapsulates, simplifies and extends. Thank you! Upvoted

Comment: @lucounu, this is what I meant by your using the `using` statement incorrectly -- you weren't declaring it into a variable.  It was hard to be sure since you had initially not posted any code.

Comment: @Kirk Woll, it should be clear now that I am in fact not using the using statement incorrectly at all. Also, your comment here is in response to someone else's answer.